# Cypress. How to use variable as attribute value

Tags: variables, attributes, cypress

I have problem with using variables. To log I use:

```
var login = 'username';
...
cy.get('#username').type(login);
```

Then username is in here:

```
<li class="dropdown" title="username" ng-click="$ctrl.bocznyPanelInformacyjny.toggle()" ow-shortcut="user">
```

How to get that title with login value?
In protractor i used:

```
this.Login = login;
element(by.css('li[title='+this.Login+']'))
```

In cypress I have Login undefined error. Tryed to google answer but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a String literal for this:

```js
var login = 'username';
cy.get(`li[title='${login}']`)
```

Comment: Very minor thing, but this is a `template string`, and not a string literal.